# Sencha EXT js Failed to resolve dependency Ext.dom.Element for file Ext.dom.ButtonElement

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, extjs6

I want to build an web app. whenever i give command in my linux terminal

```
$ sencha app build
```

to building app then i faced some dependency related problem. the errors are throws like

```
Failed to resolve dependency Ext.dom.Element for file Ext.dom.ButtonElement

 BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.dom.Element
[ERR]   at org.apache.too
[ERR] ls.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
```

It would be nice to me if anyone give suggestion that how can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the file `ext/packages/core/src/dom/Element.js` is available, and then have a look into `app.json`, whether

```
/**
 * The list of required packages (with optional versions; default is "latest").
```

contains

```
"requires": [
    "core",
```